# Guava MapSplitter to extract key-value pairs whose value can contain outer split character

Tags: regex, guava

Using Guava library, If I want to extract key-value pairs from a string(sample is below)

```
id=1234 name="Amy Winehouse" age=27
```

where

- values of keys can contain outer split character, *i.e. value of **name** key **Amy Winehouse** contains **space** character in the sample*.
- the values containing outer split character is wrapped with another character, ***double quotes*** wraps the value of **name** key in the sample.

How can I create such a `MapSplitter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
    String input = "id=1234 name=Amy fullname=\"Amy Winehouse\" age=27";

    Map<String, String> result = Splitter.onPattern("\\s(?=([^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$)")
            .withKeyValueSeparator(Splitter.onPattern("="))
            .split(input);
```

Output:

```
{id=1234, name=Amy, fullname="Amy Winehouse", age=27}
```

Comment: It does not handle inputs like the following **id=1234 name=Amy fullname="Amy Winehouse" age=27**. If a value does not contain outer split character, which is space in the example, there is no necessity to wrap it. I should have stated that in the question.